# How to display the Binary PDF data received from a web service on a Android device?

Tags: android, ios, pdf, binary, livecycle

I am working with Adobe's LiveCycle ES3 server, which returns the updatable PDF form in various formats like HTML, Binary etc.

I have tried displaying HTML using WebView and it does not work 100%.  for example it has date field and when you tap on it it brings up the Calendar icon but when I tap on the icon itself, the Calendar doesn't show up.  It does work in iPhone though.  Besides that the format is totally messed up in both iOS and Android platforms.

So, now I am trying to display the PDF form itself.  So, the form structure is sent down by the web service is in binary format (bytes), which I should use in some control to display on the Android device.

So, can anyone tell me how can I display the binary form of PDF which is stored in a memory variable on Android device, please?  Again, I cannot store this in a file for security reasons.  And since I am working on a HealthCare industry HIPAA plays a big part when it comes to security.

Thanks in advance for your great solutions...  and look forward to it...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but do you have a link to a sample PDF form that demonstrates the issue?  I'm guessing the Calendar icon click handler (and possibly some of the formatting) are using JavaScript, which is [disabled in a `WebView` by default](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript).  This can be [enabled](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript) and may fix some of the issues.

Keep in mind that depending on how you're managing the data and displaying it on the WebView is also important, as the data can be cached to the device even if you're not saving it locally within your app.  For a more robust application that works with PHI or PII, you may want to look into using the [**Device Administration API**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to create a security-aware application.

I recently used [**android-pdfview**](https://github.com/areyling/android-pdfview) (original [here](http://joanzapata.com/android-pdfview/)) for a project, which you could modify to fit your needs for working with PDF data in memory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't work on this anymore and just saw your answer.
No, I do not have any link to the PDF, I get the binary data through json or xml web service and there is no direct link to the physical pdf files.  everything is stored and manipulated through database.
But someone else is working on it using PdfTron and it seems to be working lot better than Adobe and it is lot less expensive if you want get the support otherwise it is free.